# How to Set my X and Y Of Pic To save an image C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, crop

I Have A Pic For Example ( This Pic Have a X:467 Y:300 ) I Just Need From X:0 Y:0 To X:200 Y:45 I Use This Code For Crop But I Lost Data Of X:0 Y:0 To X:200 Y:45 I Don't Know What To Do

```
bmp.Save("@image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        Image img = new Bitmap("@image.png");
        Rectangle source = new Rectangle(0, 0, ww, hh);
        Image cropped = CropImage(img, source);
        cropped.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName("@image.png") + "croppped" + Path.GetExtension("@image.png"));
    }

    private Bitmap CropImage(Image originalImage, Rectangle sourceRectangle,Rectangle? destinationRectangle = null)
    {
        if (destinationRectangle == null)
        {
            destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, sourceRectangle.Size);
        }

        var croppedImage = new Bitmap(destinationRectangle.Value.Width,
            destinationRectangle.Value.Height);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(originalImage, destinationRectangle.Value,
                sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return croppedImage;
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, your `CropImage` seems to work fine. Is this your actual code or are you by any chance providing different values for the rectangle parameters?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes this is my original code Is There a way to make an image without using original image ?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Its Working But I lost data Some how

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that when I load a random image and run it through your `CropImage` method, it's doing exactly what I would expect it to do - no data from the _left_ or _top_ of the original image is lost. I can't fix code that doesn't appear (to me at least) to be broken.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis i just want to set the size before saving bitmap Instead of crop image

Comment: @C.Evenhuis i just need to set the Height befor ssaving image

Comment: You're currently saving, loading, cropping and saving - you can skip the first save and load part by supplying `bmp` to the `CropImage` method directly. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes that is how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I understand that you want to crop the image before saving the original image to disk. In that case you can directly supply the image to the crop method:

```
    // bmp.Save("@image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    // Image img = new Bitmap("@image.png");
    Rectangle source = new Rectangle(0, 0, ww, hh);
    Image cropped = CropImage(bmp, source); // <-- bmp supplied to crop method directly
    cropped.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName("@image.png") + "croppped" + Path.GetExtension("@image.png"));
```